# Hide For Specific Pages WooCommerce Description & Additional information & Reviews Tabs Using Wordpress Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-fields

I'm attempting to make a system whereby I can remove the product tabs but only on certain single product pages, and I need to define which pages are to have their product tabs hidden using wordpress custom fields. The custom field name I want to call: 'hide_product_page_tabs' and the defining values need to be either '1' or '0' for yes or no.

I created a new Wordpress custom field on my chosen woocommerce product pages.

Custom field name: hide_product_tabs

Custom field value: Defined a '1' in the custom field to trigger the code, or anything else such as '0' to turn it off.

I placed in my child theme's functions.php :

```
/* WooCommerce hide product page tabs - hide_product_tabs */
/**
 * Remove existing tabs from single product pages.
 * https://gist.github.com/mikejolley/c75083db7f6110cbdbe4808e3af36fe3
 */
 function remove_woocommerce_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    unset( $tabs['description'] );
    unset( $tabs['reviews'] );
    unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );
    return $tabs;
}
function hide_product_page_tabs() {
        global $post;
        $product_id = $post->ID;
        $HideProductTabsValue =  get_post_meta($product_id,'hide_product_tabs',true);
        if (strpos($HideProductTabsValue, '1') !== false) {
        return add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'remove_woocommerce_product_tabs', 98 );
        }
}       
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','hide_product_page_tabs');
```

Any tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, without seeing the code you use for this, you can simply use the following

```php
function hide_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    // Get the global product object
    global $product;

    // Get product id
    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

    $HideProductTabsValue = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'hide_product_tabs', true);

    // 1 = true
    if( $HideProductTabsValue == true ) {
        unset( $tabs['description'] ); // (Description tab)  
        unset( $tabs['reviews'] ); // (Reviews tab)
        unset( $tabs['additional_information'] ); // (Additional information tab)       
    }

    return $tabs;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'hide_product_tabs', 98 );
```

Comment: Superb! Thank you so much!